# r - arrange values in column based on unique values in another column within a group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to reorder column in a dataframe, in a descending or ascending order, based on unique values of another column in the same dataframe within groups.

To demonstrate this below is given an example in which a dataframe has three columns. The goal is to group by the `gr` column, and to order the `a` column based on the unique value of the `b` column. So for example if within the `gr=1` the unique value of the column `b` is T then I would like the column `a` in ascending order, and if not in descending order. The example is below

```
# sample dataset
df <-  data.frame(
    a = c(1,3,2,4),
    b = c(T,T,F,F),
    gr = c(1,1,2,2)
  )

# split dataset according to a grouping column
df <- df %>% split(df$gr)

# ordering function
f1 <- function(dt) {
  if (unique(dt$b) == T) {
    arrange(dt, a)
  } else {
    arrange(dt, -a)
  }
}
```

The desired dataset should look like this:

```
# order within groups based on variable b
df %>% purrr::map_df(f1)
```

Can this be done without using lists or `tidyr::nest` ? Using a simple `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::arrange` it should be possible and is the best desired answer.

Comment: if you take a closer look at the var `a` you can see it has been reordered. Originally it is c(1,3,2,4), and at the end it is c(1,3,4,2)

Comment: a reordering has been done. Instead of 2,4; a 4,2 is required

Comment: Let's say if you have more rows and there are  TRUE/FALSE for a particular group, how would the order change

Comment: two different values are not allowed in a group

Comment: `df %>% arrange(gr, a * if_else(b, 1, -1))`

Comment: d.b this is the most simple solution that works. But I will accept Akruns since it was the fastest reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `arrange` alone without doing any `split`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(gr, c(1, -1)[gr] * a)
#  a     b gr
#1 1  TRUE  1
#2 3  TRUE  1
#3 4 FALSE  2
#4 2 FALSE  2
```

or if it needs to be with 'b'

```
df %>% 
   arrange(gr, c(-1, 1)[(b + 1)] * a)
#  a     b gr
#1 1  TRUE  1
#2 3  TRUE  1
#3 4 FALSE  2
#4 2 FALSE  2
```

Here, we make use of the `numeric` 'gr'.  If it is not `numeric`, create the grouping index with `match` and use that to change values of 'a'

```
df %>%
   arrange(gr, c(1, -1)[match(gr, unique(gr))] * a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.

```
library(dplyr)

f2 <- function(dt) {
  2*as.integer(df$b) - 1
}

df %>% arrange(gr, a*f2())
```

If you accept the rearrangement of the column `gr`, remove it from `arrange`.

```
df %>% arrange(a*f2())
```

**Edit.**

Simpler?

```
f2 <- function(x) 2*x - 1

df %>% arrange(gr, a*f2(b))
```

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva Note that the call to `as.integer` is not needed at all, R will coerce the logical to integer, I wrote it like this to make it more clear. In *real* code, remove it.

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva If you liked it, see the edit.